# How to import an array of PSObjects from a text file?

Tags: string, powershell, csv, text-processing, psobject

This is [simple](https://lazyadmin.nl/powershell/import-csv-powershell/) enough:

```
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\data>
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\data> ls .\test.csv


    Directory: C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\data


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2023-01-31   1:38 PM            640 test.csv


PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\data>
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\data> cat .\test.csv
UserPrincipalName,"DisplayName","Title","UserType","IsLicensed"
LeeG@lazydev.com,"Lee Gu","jr engineer","Member","True"
MeganB@lazydev.com,"Megan Bowen","recruiter","Member","True"
GradyA@lazydev.com,"Grady Archie","sr engineer","Member","True"
MiriamG@lazydev.com,"Miriam Graham","Director","Member","True"
openmailbox@lazydev.com,"openmailbox",,"Member","False"
JohannaL@lazydev.com,"Johanna Lorenz","Senior Engineer","Member","True"
JoniS@lazydev.com,"Joni Sherman","recruiter","Member","False"
AlexW@lazydev.com,"Alex Wilber","Marketing Assistant","Member","True"
IsaiahL@lazydev.com,"Isaiah Langer","Sales Rep","Member","True"
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\data>
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\data> $test = Import-CSV .\test.csv
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\data>
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\data> $test[3]


UserPrincipalName : MiriamG@lazydev.com
DisplayName       : Miriam Graham
Title             : Director
UserType          : Member
IsLicensed        : True



PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\data>
```

But how would CSV formatted data be obtained from a formatted **text** file?

```
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\data>
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\data> $records = Get-Content .\records.txt
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\data>
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\data> $records


UserPrincipalName : LeeG@lazydev.com
DisplayName       : Lee Gu
Title             : jr engineer
UserType          : Member
IsLicensed        : True

UserPrincipalName : MeganB@lazydev.com
DisplayName       : Megan Bowen
Title             : recruiter
UserType          : Member
IsLicensed        : True

UserPrincipalName : GradyA@lazydev.com
DisplayName       : Grady Archie
Title             : sr engineer
UserType          : Member
IsLicensed        : True

UserPrincipalName : MiriamG@lazydev.com
DisplayName       : Miriam Graham
Title             : Director
UserType          : Member
IsLicensed        : True

UserPrincipalName : openmailbox@lazydev.com
DisplayName       : openmailbox
Title             :
UserType          : Member
IsLicensed        : False

UserPrincipalName : JohannaL@lazydev.com
DisplayName       : Johanna Lorenz
Title             : Senior Engineer
UserType          : Member
IsLicensed        : True

UserPrincipalName : JoniS@lazydev.com
DisplayName       : Joni Sherman
Title             : recruiter
UserType          : Member
IsLicensed        : False

UserPrincipalName : AlexW@lazydev.com
DisplayName       : Alex Wilber
Title             : Marketing Assistant
UserType          : Member
IsLicensed        : True

UserPrincipalName : IsaiahL@lazydev.com
DisplayName       : Isaiah Langer
Title             : Sales Rep
UserType          : Member
IsLicensed        : True

PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\data>
```

So that the data for each record is transposed and then written to a row in a CSV file.  No doubt there's a [term](https://java2blog.com/write-array-to-csv-powershell/) for this inverse operation.  It doesn't have to be CSV per se, it's just that the above sample originates as CSV.

Please do correct any terminological errors.

---

as it stands, no the $records object cannot itself be directly exported back to CSV with:

```
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\data>
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\data> $records = Get-Content .\records.txt
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\data>
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\data> Export-Csv $records
Export-Csv : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Path'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:1 char:12
+ Export-Csv $records
+            ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand

PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\data>
```

as it will first have to parsed somehow.

Comment: Are you able to re-export the data in the correct format using `Export-Csv` ?

Comment: no @SantiagoSquarzon and I added the error.  Bear in mind that it's originating as a text file, so it's almost a RegEx parsing question.  But, I would think, a bit different...?

Comment: Yes, you need text parsing to convert that into objects. Which makes me sad this was exported this way to begin with :(

Comment: you're only sad @SantiagoSquarzon whereas...

Comment: Leaving open for elaboration on `help ConvertFrom-StringData` versus `help ConvertFrom-String` as is relevant to the question.  When all you have is a hammer everything looks like a nail.  There's more than one way to skin this cat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Windows PowerShell specifically, you have the option of using [`ConvertFrom-String`'s template-based parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-string?view=powershell-5.1) capability:

```
# define a template using the data from 2 consecutive records from the input data
$recordTemplate = @'
UserPrincipalName : {UserPrincipalName*:LeeG@lazydev.com}
DisplayName       : {DisplayName:Lee Gu}
Title             : {Title:jr engineer}
UserType          : {UserType:Member}
IsLicensed        : {IsLicensed:True}

UserPrincipalName : {UserPrincipalName*:MeganB@lazydev.com}
'@

# ConvertFrom-String will use the example(s) in the template to infer the format of the remaining records
Get-Content .\records.txt | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $recordTemplate
```

Comment: I'm looking at `help ConvertFrom-StringData` now.

Comment: @NicholasSaunders That's a different cmdlet :)

Comment: It is available in pwsh Core via implicit remoting

Answer (score 3):

The text format your showing is a *for-display* format, as produced by PowerShell's [`Format-List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list) cmdlet.

As such, it isn't meant for *programmatic* processing, so there's no standard cmdlet that can parse that format (see bottom section re `ConvertFrom-String`).

For *programmatic* processing, a *structured* text format should be used, such as JSON or CSV, or - for the most structural flexibility and best (albeit limited) type fidelity - PowerShell's XML-based CLIXML format, as produced by [`Export-Clixml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-clixml) and understood by [`Import-Clixml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-clixml).

If you're stuck with the given format, you'll have to do your own parsing; e.g.:

```
# Outputs [pscustomobject] instances that can be exported to CSV, for instance.
((Get-Content -Raw records.txt) -replace ':', '=') -split '\r?\n\r?\n' | 
  ConvertFrom-StringData | 
  ForEach-Object { [pscustomobject] $_ }
```

The above is relatively simple, but:

- assumes that none of the property *values* contain `:` (this could be worked around) and that all values are *single-line*; also, the values are subject to interpretation of `\` chars. as the start of escape sequence (see cmdlet link in next bullet point).
- has one *unavoidable* drawback: because [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata) outputs inherently *unordered* [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables), the property order isn't preserved.

  - Potentially fixing this problem in a future PowerShell version (post-7.3.2, current as of this writing) is the subject of [GitHub issue #19070](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19070)

If maintaining the property order is important, and you know the property names, you can pipe to a `Select-Object` call with the property names listed in the desired order as its `-Property` argument.

Otherwise, you'll have to parse the text-file lines yourself.

---

Note: I **suggest *avoiding* the obsolescent, Windows-only [`ConvertFrom-String`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-string) cmdlet**, despite its allure:

- It provides separator-based parsing as well as *heuristics*-based parsing based on templates containing example values.
- The separator-based parsing applies *automatic type conversions* that you cannot control, and the template language is poorly documented, with the exact behavior being hard to predict (as is unavoidable in a *heuristics*-based solution).
- That said, even though it **has been *removed* from [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, *on Windows* you can still call it, namely via the [Windows PowerShell Compatibility feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Windows_PowerShell_Compatibility), which, however, incurs a noticeable *performance penalty*.

Answer (score 0):

While not fully realized, something like

```
wsl >
wsl > pwd
/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32/awk
wsl >
wsl > awk '{print $1}' input.txt | datamash transpose
A       B       C       D
wsl >
wsl > awk '{print $2}' input.txt | datamash transpose
2014    2013    2014    2014
wsl >
wsl > awk '{print $3}' input.txt | datamash transpose
1002    990     2030    599
wsl >
wsl > cat input.txt
A        2014   1002
B        2013    990
C        2014   2030
D        2014    599
wsl >
```

where the matrix is transposed one line at a time per record.

The output above, when concatted, would be:

```
A       B       C       D
2014    2013    2014    2014
1002    990     2030    599
```

Which, at first glance at least, would be easily imported as CSV.  Not a PowerShell solution, however.