# How to invoke ConvertFrom-String in PowerShell on Linux?

Tags: linux, string, powershell, .net-core, text-processing

Looking to use `ConvertFrom-String` on `Linux` as per the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-string?view=powershell-5.1) from the help file:

```
**********************
PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20230204142830
Username: mordor\nicholas
RunAs User: mordor\nicholas
Configuration Name: 
Machine: mordor (Unix 5.15.0.58)
Host Application: /snap/powershell/229/opt/powershell/pwsh.dll
Process ID: 1193147
PSVersion: 7.3.2
PSEdition: Core
GitCommitId: 7.3.2
OS: Linux 5.15.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 5 11:43:13 UTC 2023
Platform: Unix
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.10032.0, 6.0.0, 6.1.0, 6.2.0, 7.0.0, 7.1.0, 7.2.0, 7.3.2
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
**********************
Transcript started, output file is /home/nicholas/powershell/PowerShell_transcript.mordor.ciSjO_A6.20230204142830.txt
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> $template = @'
{Name*:Phoebe Cat}, {phone:425-123-6789}, {age:6}
{Name*:Lucky Shot}, {phone:(206) 987-4321}, {age:12}
'@
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> $testText = @'
Phoebe Cat, 425-123-6789, 6
Lucky Shot, (206) 987-4321, 12
Elephant Wise, 425-888-7766, 87
Wild Shrimp, (111)  222-3333, 1
'@
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> $PersonalData = $testText | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template

ConvertFrom-String: The term 'ConvertFrom-String' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

ConvertFrom-String: The term 'ConvertFrom-String' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> $PersonalData = $testText | ConvertFrom-StringData -TemplateContent $template
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> TerminatingError(ConvertFrom-StringData): "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'TemplateContent'."

ConvertFrom-StringData: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'TemplateContent'.

ConvertFrom-StringData: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'TemplateContent'.
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> help ConvertFrom-String
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> help ConvertFrom-StringData
PS /home/nicholas/powershell> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.3.2
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.3.2
OS                             Linux 5.15.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 5 11:43:13 UTC 2023
Platform                       Unix
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0

PS /home/nicholas/powershell> lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

what throws me off here is that the help file loads fine, which would [indicate](https://www.comparitech.com/net-admin/install-powershell-modules/) that the component is installed.  Perhaps that's an incorrect understanding.

Comment: Check the environmental variable PSModulePath.  See : https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGet/issues/218

Comment: @jdweng, `ConvertFrom-String` is a Windows PowerShell-only module, which is therefore by definition unavailable on _Linux_. (On _Windows_, it is _automatically_ available via the Windows PowerShell Compatibility feature, but there are good reasons to avoid it).

Comment: Note: `ConvertFrom-String` is not to be confused with the [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata) cmdlet, which _is_ available in PowerShell (Core) as well, on all supported platforms.

Comment: The help does _not_ load fine.  If you run `help ConvertFrom-String` on PowerShell Core, you get the help for `ConvertFrom-StringData`, which is a completely different cmdlet. `ConvertFrom-String` is simply not there in Core.

Answer (score 2):

[`ConvertFrom-String`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-string) is available *only* in *Windows PowerShell*, the legacy, Windows-only edition of PowerShell - it was never ported to [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), the modern, cross-platform edition.

- On *Windows only*, the cmdlet is technically still available, via the [Windows PowerShell compatibility feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Windows_PowerShell_Compatibility) (which comes with its own limitations); however, for the reasons stated below, it's best to avoid this cmdlet altogether.
- Note: `ConvertFrom-String` is not to be confused with the [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata) cmdlet, which *is* available in PowerShell (Core) as well, on all supported platforms; its sole focus is on parsing text in the form of *key-value pairs* into hashtables.

However, even in Windows PowerShell / on Windows there are good reasons to avoid use of `ConvertFrom-String`:

- It provides separator-based parsing as well as *heuristics*-based parsing based on templates containing example values.
- The separator-based parsing applies automatic type conversions you cannot control, and the poorly documented template language results in behavior that is inherently hard to predict.

---

As for a potential PowerShell (Core)-native *substitute* for `ConvertFrom-String`: *there is none*. Depending on the use case, one of the following may help for parsing data that is structured in a nonstandard manner:

- For parsing text in the form of key-value pairs into [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables), possibly with preprocessing, use `ConvertFrom-StringData` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75303797/45375) for an example.
- Otherwise, *general text-parsing techniques* are required:

  - On Unix-like platforms, native utilities such as `awk` and `sed` may help (possibly for transformation into a standard format that PowerShell cmdlets can then parse into objects).
  - PowerShell's [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement has `awk`-like capabilities, and its [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) and [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operators offer powerful [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) processing.

Comment: So `regex` would be a reasonable approach on Linux?

Comment: @NicholasSaunders, either that, or a `Convert-FromStringData` approach, possibly with some pre-processing, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75303797/45375) to one of your previous questions. Honestly, `ConvertFrom-String` is a dead end, and I suggest neither using it nor accepting answers that use it.

Comment: This answers completely omits the myriad of CLI tools that have unstructured formats and that will always exist and be part of our workflow and thus need to be handled and converted to shell objects if we want to do any simple parsing or manipulation on it. `ConvertFrom-String` **was** providing easy parsing and absolutely not "hard to predict" behavior with classic character-separated output as explained in more detail in this [post](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/726#issuecomment-1783789067). ->

Comment: -> It's precisely the absence of that cmdlet that finds us now having a hard time parsing outputs of such commands. `ConvertFrom-StringData` **does not** replace `ConvertFrom-String` as it only creates a hash table i.e. only works for output having two rows exactly. The latter worked for any amount of rows. And as for your linked example, it's pointless as you practically never have an ouput in this form but always in the form of character-separated rows with the header (first line) providing the "property" names. That's exactly why `ConvertFrom-String` was created in the first place.

Comment: @adamency: This answer addresses the question _as asked_: it explains that `Convert-FromString` isn't available in _PowerShell (Core)_ - nothing more and nothing less. 
As a bonus, it explains why there are reasons to avoid it even in _Windows PowerShell_  and that on Windows you _can_ still use it, albeit via the  - slow and generally type-fidelity-limited - Windows Compatibility feature.
Nothing more and nothing less. `ConvertFrom-StringData` is mentioned as an _aside_, in a _comment_, and it is an alternative _in certain scenarios_, such as the _very specific one_ in the linked answer.